# What are "rashei pispasin"?

Tags: words, commentaries, beis-hamikdash, mishna, masechet-midot

In Middot 2:6 and 4:5, it says that רָאשֵׁי פִסְפָּסִין divided between different areas of the Beit haMikdash, specifically between the Ezrat Kohanim and Ezrat Yisrael, and between the areas above the Kodesh and Kodesh haKodashim in the upper story of the Heikhal.

This term is often translated something like "ends of beams" (as for example in the Artscroll and Sefaria editions of the Mishna), which is still vague. What are some different commentators' explanations of what רָאשֵׁי פִסְפָּסִין looked like?

Comment: פשפש is a little gate

Comment: Did you check any commentators there?

Comment: @mevaqesh Perhaps I don't have the source text available to me now, or perhaps my Hebrew skills are too lacking to read commentaries.

Comment: I am not accusing you of anything, but clarifying what research you have done, if any, can be helpful to others so they don't duplicate your research. You could also indicate if this frequent translation refers to commentators, or to some other translation.